# Downloaded a Java library off GitHub, do I compile it now?

Tags: java, github

I am trying to do this simple tutorial using the JARVIS Java Speech API:
https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api/wiki/Hello-World

These import lines lead me to think that I need to link to a .jar library.

```
import com.darkprograms.speech.microphone.Microphone;
import com.darkprograms.speech.recognizer.Recognizer;
import com.darkprograms.speech.recognizer.GoogleResponse;
```

But when I go to the [gitHub site](https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api), the only option is to download the .java source files. How should I go about converting them into a .jar? Is that what I am supposed to do?

Comment: In Command prompt use `jar cf MyApp1.jar C:\JavaProject\MyApp`

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse/

Comment: Make sure you have all the dependencies in classpath before compiling the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that same GitHub page, you can download the jar :

https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api/releases

You should also acquire any additional jar required by Jarvis (it doesn't seem there are any from a quick look).

That said, if you want the very last version of that library (and the associated bug/problems if any), then you will need to compile it from source, ie, something like :

- clone the git repositery
- compile the java sources
- create the jar

Comment: Understood, thank you. And I would use something like ANT or SBT to build classes correct? I know about the javac command but read that its not easy to compile when the .java source files are scattered across many folders.

Comment: The best way would be to use the same system as the developper. For this case, I do not see anything so I would import the project in eclipse ide and then use Eclipse fonctions (Export Jar..) to build it.